# Flask Download a File

Tags: python, flask, download, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a web app with Flask that lets a user upload a file and serve them to another user. Right now, I can upload the file to the *upload_folder* correctly. But I can't seem to find a way to let the user download it back.

I'm storing the name of the filename into a database.

I have a view serving the database objects. I can delete them too.

```
@app.route('/dashboard', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def dashboard():

    problemes = Probleme.query.all()

    if 'user' not in session:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        delete = Probleme.query.filter_by(id=request.form['del_button']).first()
        db.session.delete(delete)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

    return render_template('dashboard.html', problemes=problemes)
```

In my HTML I have:

```
<td><a href="{{ url_for('download', filename=probleme.facture) }}">Facture</a></td>
```

and a download view :

```
@app.route('/uploads/<path:filename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def download(filename):
    return send_from_directory(directory=app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename=filename)
```

But it's returning :

> Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

I just want to link the filename to the object and let the user download it (For every object in the same view)

Comment: For what URL does Flask return a 404 Not Found response? Have you verified that the filename in question really resides in `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']`?

Comment: It does, because I have an upload forms that really did upload the file. I just can't download it. The uploading to the folder is fine. The url is : http://127.0.0.1:5000/uploads/rsc_chapitre17.pdf and the file is really there !

Comment: The reason I ask is because `send_from_directory()` will raise a `NotFound` when there is no file there. So `os.path.isfile(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']/filename)` returned false. You need to doublecheck the contents of `UPLOAD_FOLDER` and verify that the filename you are trying to load is *really* there.

Comment: It is there, changed app = Flask(__name__) to app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='uploads') and for some reasons it worked.

Comment: Sounds like you are getting a not-found for the `/static/filename` route then instead of `/uploads/filename`.

Comment: Yah, I don't really get it but it's working... I'll keep it this way :S

Comment: I'm not sure that that is a good idea; you now are mixing static assets with uploads.

Comment: It *sounds* as if `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']` does not contain what you think it contains. What is it set to?

Comment: to '/uploads/' , maybe its the slashes ? It was it. I changed '/uploads/' to 'uploads it's working ! Thanks to you !

Comment: Python deals with the trailing slash just fine. It is the **leading** slash that is the issue here. You have defined an absolute path, not a relative one.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You need to make sure that the value you pass to the `directory` argument is an absolute path, corrected for the *current* location of your application.

The best way to do this is to configure `UPLOAD_FOLDER` as a relative path (no leading slash), then make it absolute by prepending `current_app.root_path`:

```
@app.route('/uploads/<path:filename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def download(filename):
    uploads = os.path.join(current_app.root_path, app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
    return send_from_directory(uploads, filename)
```

It is important to reiterate that `UPLOAD_FOLDER` must be relative for this to work, e.g. not start with a `/`.

A relative path *could* work but relies too much on the current working directory being set to the place where your Flask code lives. This may not always be the case.

Comment: Flask 2.0 [replaced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67591487/673991) the required `filename=` parameter with `path=`. I suspect the new optional filename parameter is the client-side name but the [doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory) doesn't say. Double eye roll emoji.

Comment: @BobStein: the `filename` parameter is gone entirely now, but it only existed in the 2.0.x and 2.1.x series of releases to [trigger a warning](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/2.0.x/src/flask/helpers.py#L691-L698) (so, if you used it, you'd see a message that your should use `path=` now). You can use the names as positional arguments in any version.

Answer (score 98):

> **To download file on flask call.** File name is **Examples.pdf**
>   When I am hitting **127.0.0.1:5000/download** it should get
>   download.

Example:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import send_file
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/download')
def downloadFile ():
    #For windows you need to use drive name [ex: F:/Example.pdf]
    path = "/Examples.pdf"
    return send_file(path, as_attachment=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000,debug=True)
```

Comment: This doesn't actually address the question, which uses a variable path element to name the file to download.

Comment: It doesn't matter. question with high SEO rank + general title `Flask Download a File` should be answered more generally on purpose IMO

Comment: Beautifully simple. Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: I get the impression `send_from_directory()` may be [safer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24578372/673991) than `send_file()`.

Answer (score 10):

```
#HTML Code
 
<ul>
 {% for file in files %}
  <li> <a href="{{ url_for('download', filename=file) }}">{{ file }}</a></li>
 {% endfor %}
</ul>


#Python Code

from flask import send_from_directory

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']='logs'


@app.route('/uploads/<path:filename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def download(filename):
    print(app.root_path)
    full_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
    print(full_path)
    return send_from_directory(full_path, filename)
```

Answer (score 8):

I was also developing a similar application. I was also getting not found error even though the file was there. This solve my problem. I mention my download folder in 'static_folder':

```
app = Flask(__name__,static_folder='pdf')
```

My code for the download is as follows:

```
@app.route('/pdf/<path:filename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def download(filename):    
    return send_from_directory(directory='pdf', filename=filename)
```

This is how I am calling my file from html.

```
<a class="label label-primary" href=/pdf/{{  post.hashVal }}.pdf target="_blank"  style="margin-right: 5px;">Download pdf </a>
<a class="label label-primary" href=/pdf/{{  post.hashVal }}.png target="_blank"  style="margin-right: 5px;">Download png </a>
```

Comment: You don't need or even *want* to set `static_folder` to point to your pdf subdirectory too. That just means that everything from the `/static/` path is *also* being served from the `pdf `subfolder. And as I stated in my answer: *A relative path **could** work but relies too much on the current working directory being set to the place where your Flask code lives.*; your relative path in `directory='pdf'` is going to fall in that trap too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this(assuming UPLOAD_FOLDER is relative to your working directory).

```
@app.route('/uploads/<path:filename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def download(filename):
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
    return send_from_directory(directory=path, filename=filename)
```