# Is it possible for Flask to display data from a list and provide a download link?

Tags: python, flask

I have created a Flask app that creates a list and returns the list to an HTML page. I would also like to make the list downloadable as a CSV file.

So far I understand how to do these tasks as separate functions.

Is there a way to combine these functions into one so that a list is created only once, displaying the data on an HTML template, and also providing a download link?

Please view the basic examples below:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    fruits = ['apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'grapes', 'mango']
    return render_template('fruit.html', fruit=fruits)


@app.route('/fruits.csv')
def generate_fruit_file():
    def generate():
        fruits = ['apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'grapes', 'mango']
        for f in fruits:
            yield ''.join(f) + '\n'
    return Response(generate(), mimetype='text/csv')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
{% for f in fruit %}
    <ul>
        <li style="display: block;">{{ f }}</li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
    <a href="{{'/fruits.csv'}}">get file</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe your question lacks a bit of context. When you say that your application generates a list of things, that implies the list is generated from some data. Where is that data stored?

Comment: you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577349/flask-download-a-file

Comment: Born2Discover: The data is created from an API call and stored onto a database. In my main project I use a generator function to collect the data. I then store the output of the generator to a list object before saving it to the database and displaying it on the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to define a global variable `fruits` in your module that you access from each function.

```
fruits = ['apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'grapes', 'mango']

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    global fruits
    return render_template('fruit.html', fruit=fruits)


@app.route('/fruits.csv')
def generate_fruit_file():
    def generate():
        global fruits
        for f in fruits:
            yield ''.join(f) + '\n'
    return Response(generate(), mimetype='text/csv')
```

Comment: I initially tried this. It works great in debug mode but not in production. Maybe using flask.g is an option?

Comment: That is strange. What error are you getting? `Flask.g` won't work as it only stores values during one request. In your case you have two separate requests: one request to display your html file and one to download the csv.

Comment: Bear in mind the code I submitted was a resemblance to the project I am working on. The function that collects the data and generates the list can easily send the data to a global variable. I have an issue with returning that data from another function. The data is gone by the time the file output function can collect it resulting in empty files.

Comment: I might be missing something but If you store your data in a global list it will be accessible from all function as long as your server runs. The data can not be just gone.

Comment: I have found that I can print the contents of the list from within the first function. If I try the same for the function to create the file, it returns an empty list. I agree with you that the data should still be in that list but it seems as though the second function can not access it properly if at all.

Comment: Came back to say it does indeed work and it did not before due to my own error.