# Python Flask API Returning CSV Content But File Not Downloading (Google Chrome)

Tags: python, flask, download, http-headers

I've written an API to return a CSV to a user based on content they fill into a form in a web application. When running the code below, I can see the response in my console and am certain that the content is properly being returned by my API, but I can't seem to get the file to automatically start downloading.

```
csv = final_df.to_csv()
response = make_response(csv)
response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=export.csv"
response.headers['Content-type'] = "application/force-download"
return response
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577349/flask-download-a-file) will help you with your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working example of mine differs by quoting the filename (which the [Developer Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) hint at being required), and using a correct mimetype.

Try

```
return bytes(csv, encoding='UTF-8'), 200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/csv',
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="export.csv"'}
```

Comment: Unfortunately still no luck with the forced download with this solution. Tested in Chrome, IE, and Firefox.

Comment: I noticed the code I pulled that from was still Python2.7, and made one change (to the bytes() call) for Python3. It works for me on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I'm wondering if maybe there's something going on with my network settings that might be preventing the download, since I also added an encoding to get the solution to run. I ended up keeping your solution to return my response, but had to write something client side to prompt the file download.